# How to create a swift file that define buttons or textFields in XCTest?

Tags: swift, user-interface, xctest

How to create a swift file that define buttons or textFields in XCTest? I have a file UITest. I want define elements in UITest in other swift file, but it's error. This is what i'm looking for:

```
import Foundation

class HomeVC{

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tabBarsQuery = app.tabBars
    let tablesQuery = app.tables

    let btn = app.buttons["a"]
    let btn2 = app.buttons.element(boundBy: 0)
    let txt = app.tables.staticTexts["a"]

}
```

I want use those elements in my UI Test:

```
import XCTest

class UITests: XCTestCase {

    let config = TestConfig()
    let log = Log()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        XCUIApplication().launch()

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()

    }
    func testExample() {

    //Call HomeVC
    let homeVC = HomeVC()
    homeVC.btn.tap()
    homeVC.btn2.tap()
    homeVC.txt.tap()
}
```

Is there any solutions are available? please guide me through a proper solution.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, those constants which are `XCUIElement`s, rather than `XCUIElementQuery`s are resolved immediately on initialisation of the `HomeVC` class. If the buttons aren't all there when `HomeVC` is initialised, the properties will not be viable to use.

You *could* make the properties lazy, meaning that they would be resolved when they are first used, rather than on object initialization, but this is not an extensible model.

You *should* use the page object model, where you create a class for each discrete page. That class can encapsulate all the paths and identifiers to different elements, and expose the elements as computed properties. This means that the element queries will be resolved every time they are accessed, using the most up-to-date view hierarchy at the time.

There's more information about implementing the page object model with XCTest in Swift on my blog: http://qualitytesting.tumblr.com/post/144462182209/xctest-and-the-page-object-model